# How to handle bug report where question need to be migrated?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bug-reporting-process

I realise in this instance that the mere fact of the existence of this question will suffice to solve it due to the meta effect, but what would you do more generally?

---

I've seen a behaviour today on SO that doesn't seem right, so was going to report a bug for it.  However, someone else has already done so, but [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871241/show-more-comments-button-has-broken) is on the main site and hasn't yet garnered enough votes to move it across to meta, and is likely already buried under a mass of other questions in the popular tags it's got.

I could create another question here reporting the same thing, then if/when the original one gets moved it just becomes a duplicate, but that doesn't seem entirely fair on the OP of the other question.

What would you do?

Comment: Typically, it's been migrated while I was writing this...

Comment: @Laurel any reason you removed that tag?  Seems relevant since this question is about bug-reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is new, like in this case, just follow the normal procedure of voting to close as **Off Topic > Belongs on another site**. If the question is older and it looks like it's run out of close vote steam, you can leave a comment asking the OP to move it, or bring it up in a chat room to see if you can get a few more votes that way. That should be pretty easy for migrations to Meta, since there are always people around.

Comment: Thanks - didn't think of Chat, that's the obvious route for the future!